# Metro Bundler not running: After upgrading react native version

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have upgraded my app from React Native version 0.57 to 0.60.0 but after executing react-native run-android, the configurations in gradle executes successfully, but metro bundler isn't launched. And app crashes immediately after that.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use:

```
react-native upgrade --legacy=true
```

Beware that it will ask if you want to replace current android/ios files for new ones and then it will rebuild them.

Also, you need to check if your old dependencies are available on autolink, and if not you can try to link them.

Comment: I have done that. But after the version upgrade, my metro bundler doesn't run. That's the only issue.